# Moving elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just messing around with Javascript and JQuery and I've been trying to achieve an effect that I've seen around on the web recently, albiet in a much simpler form.

What I am trying to do is have a div move horizontally when the user scrolls. My thought, for a simple prototype, involves watching the scrollbar position, and whenever it travels 1% of the page, move the div a certain increment.

```
//Script
var percent = Math.round((1/100)*document.height);
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxpos = 10;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(pos%percent==0){
            boxpos+=10;
            $("#box").css("{left:"+boxpos+";}");
        }
    });
});


//css
#content{width:100%; height:4000px;}
#res{position:fixed; left:20px;}
#box{position:fixed; width:20px; height:20px; left:10px; background-color:#F66;}

//html
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="box"><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <p id="res"></p>
</div>

</body>
```

One thing I've been having problem with is that the value of `percent` never seems to be as it should, and most of the time is 0. I cannot understand why that should be.

I'm a beginner to programming so any and all comments are welcome. Am I approaching this in a poor way?

Thanks!

Edit: To give you all a better idea of what I am talking about: http://nizoapp.com/

Comment: where is p defined from if(pos%p==0)? Is p supposed to be percent?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to change that, I originally called `percent` "p", but for sake of readability I changed it all to percent. Sorry about that.

Comment: pos%percent is "pos modulo percent". Modulo is the remainder of the two numbers divided. e.g. 10 % 3 will be 1 (10/3 = 9. remainder is 1).  Is that the correct logic for this?

Comment: Yeah, I think so... if percent is 40, then when the scrollbar reaches 120, it should have gone 3%, no?

Comment: So you want the element to move horizontally when user scrolls vertically?

Comment: actually 120%40 will be 0 because 120/40 = 3. no remainder.  I have done this before though.  `(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) / document.height` will get you the percentage of the bottom of the window.  (scrolled all the way to the bottom results in 1. scrolled half way is 0.5)  Would that code snippet help you?

Comment: Correct. I'm sure my method is fairly poor, so feel free to straighten me out if you wish.
@Joseph Well yeah, it is my intention that 120%40 = 0. My idea was that it continually checks pos%percent and when that equals 0, i know that the page has scrolled yet another percent. Ill try your snippet though, Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CmCSL/ there you can find my method of calculating percent if it helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var percent = Math.round((1/100)*$(document).height());
$(document).ready(function(){
    var boxpos = 10;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
        if(pos%percent==0){
            boxpos+=10;
            $("#box").css("left", boxpos);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uh, I doesn't seem to be working. For some reason the Developer Console on chrome is complaining about Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null on line 18 (which is the line defining percent). However, when I enter the same thing into the console, there are no errors...